# register_block_type is not working properly

Tags: php, functions, ajax, block-editor

When I try to get data with ajax, the `register_block_type` function is not firing the callback method.

```
    register_block_type(
        $this->name,
        array(
            'attributes' => $this->attribute_proto,
            'render_callback' => array($this, 'render_callback')
        )
    )
```

it should fire the `render_callback` method, it's not working in ajax mode but working in PHP mode

Comment: In what context are you trying to register a block via AJAX?

Comment: @JacobPeattie I have a dynamic block to show blog posts, I need to add ajax load more on this block in the front-end and I need to register this block because I need block attributes